# Java: download web content with special characters in url

Tags: java, download

I am downloading a webpage content but the address has special characters. For example, it contain word `adiós` in the `myUrl`. I am using the below code, but it is not successful. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks

```
String myUrl="http://www.somethingxxxxx.com/adiós";   
URLConnection yc = new URL(myUrl).openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                yc.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to encode your URL before you use it. To do this, you can try something like:

```
try {
    String base = "http://www.somethingxxxxx.com/";
    String toEncode = "adiós";
    String myEncodedUrl = base + URLEncoder.encode( toEncode, "UTF-8" );
    URLConnection yc = new URL(myEncodedUrl).openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                            yc.getInputStream()));
} catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException exc ) {
   exc.printStackTrace();
} catch ( IOException exc ) {
   exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class instead of java.netURL